# Return hashset values as ints

Tags: java, int, return, loops, hashset

Simple question.  I'm iterating through a Java hashset and want to return each value as an int.  I've been using the code below to at least print the values.  The function is a class method and 'neighbors' is a hashset within the class.

```
      neighbors = new HashSet<Integer>();

      void get_n(){
        Iterator it = neighbors.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
          print(it.next()); // ideally, I would change this
        }
      }
```

How do I modify the code so I can **return** (not print) each element as an int instead?

Comment: What does your HashSet contains?? I mean type of elements??

Comment: What type is 'neighbours' ? What's stored in it ?

Comment: And what do you mean by : - `return (not print) each element as an int`?? You can only return once from any method..

Comment: What exactly do you want to return? An array of `int`s?

Comment: And returning an array of ints would be fine

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want, but here's a starting point:

```
List<Integer> get_n(){
    Iterator it = neighbors.iterator();
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while(it.hasNext()){
      list.add(((Number)it.next()).intValue());
    }
    return list;
}
```

Your `Iterator it` is untyped (doesn't have generic type), so I'm assuming you need downcasting. However if your `neighbors` `HashSet` was actually `HashSet<Integer>`, then your code could be simplified to:

```
new ArrayList<Integer>(neighbors);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the genericised [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) then the iterator will be similarly typed, and it.next() will return the correct type.

That's a long way of saying that if you declare your `HashSet` as `HashSet<Integer>` then the iterator will return a (boxable) `Integer`. You'll be able to return `Integer` or `int` via the magic of [boxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html).

Answer (score 0):

haha

you may want something like 'yield '

try lombok-pg
https://github.com/peichhorn/lombok-pg/wiki/Yield